# MySQL update join from select very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join, database-performance

We have a stored procedure that is used to prepare data for a report.  Note that the schema isn't as normalized as it should be, but it is what it is and we cannot modify it, hence building the temporary table for the report. MySQL version is 5.1.70.

There is an update statement that updated the temp table from a join to a select. Note that all columns in this query that should have an index do, including the temp table (OI):

```
UPDATE `tmpOrderInquiry` OI
INNER JOIN (
SELECT `SalesOrderNo`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(Inv.`InvoiceNo` ORDER BY `InvoiceNo` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `InvoiceNoGRP`, 
    GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date(`ShipDate`), ' %c/%d/%y') ORDER BY `ShipDate` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `ShipDateGRP`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date(`LastPmtDate`), ' %c/%d/%y') ORDER BY `LastPmtDate` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `LastPmtDateGRP`
    FROM `InsynchInvoiceHistoryHeader` Inv 
    GROUP BY Inv.`SalesOrderNo`
    ) as OrdInv ON OI.`SalesOrderNo` = OrdInv.`SalesOrderNo`
SET OI.`InvoiceNo` = OrdInv.`InvoiceNoGRP`, OI.`ShipDate` = OrdInv.`ShipDateGRP`, OI.`LastPmtDate` = OrdInv.`LastPmtDateGRP`
```

This query takes approximately 70 seconds on average to complete.  The select on its own executes sub-second.  After much head banging, on a lark I replaced the above with:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `tempWorking` AS SELECT 
    `SalesOrderNo`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(Inv.`InvoiceNo` ORDER BY `InvoiceNo` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `InvoiceNoGRP`, 
        GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date(`ShipDate`), ' %c/%d/%y') ORDER BY `ShipDate` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `ShipDateGRP`,
        GROUP_CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(date(`LastPmtDate`), ' %c/%d/%y') ORDER BY `LastPmtDate` ASC SEPARATOR '~|~') as `LastPmtDateGRP`
        FROM `InsynchInvoiceHistoryHeader` Inv 
        GROUP BY Inv.`SalesOrderNo`;
UPDATE `tmpOrderInquiry` OI
INNER JOIN tempWorking as OrdInv ON OI.`SalesOrderNo` = OrdInv.`SalesOrderNo`
SET OI.`InvoiceNo` = OrdInv.`InvoiceNoGRP`, OI.`ShipDate` = OrdInv.`ShipDateGRP`, OI.`LastPmtDate` = OrdInv.`LastPmtDateGRP`
```

This query runs in about 2 seconds. Since the select itself is fast, I am at a loss to explain why the first query is so slow. Because the problem was acute I released this change to production but I don't like introducing a fix that all things being equal I would expect to actually make things slower.

Any insight as to why the first update statement is so slow would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there any chance that you add an index to `tempworking`?

Comment: tempworking isn't in the first slow query.  I will probably revise the 2nd method and optimize it if I decide to keep it.  tmporderinquiry has the necessary indexes.